# Docker Operator fail in Airflow MWAA

Tags: python, airflow, amazon-ecr, mwaa, dockeroperator

We are trying to use docker operator in Airflow(MWAA). We are storing docker images in ECR repository in same AWS account. The Airflow DAG with docker operator fails with below error

**Log**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 714, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 415, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 244, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 975, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 27, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 798, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 550, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 769, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 714, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 415, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 244, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1037, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 975, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 27, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
    return self.version(api_version=False)["ApiVersion"]
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 602, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 501, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py", line 459, in execute
    if self.force_pull or not self.cli.images(name=self.image):
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/operators/docker.py", line 329, in cli
    return self.hook.api_client
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/functools.py", line 981, in __get__
    val = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/docker/hooks/docker.py", line 120, in api_client
    client = APIClient(
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 221, in _retrieve_server_version
    raise DockerException(
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
```

Airflow Version: v2.6.3

**Code**

```
# dbt docker image name from Airflow variables
dbt_image = (
    "{{ var.value.get('DBT_IMAGE') }}" 
)

refresh_function = PythonOperator(
    task_id="refresh_ecr_creds", python_callable=refresh_ecr_credentials
)

run_dbt_task = DockerOperator(
    task_id="dbt_run_fct_sample",
    image=dbt_image,
    api_version="auto",
    auto_remove=True,
    command=["run", "-s", "fct_sample"],  # Replace with dbt commands
    dag=dag,
    docker_conn_id=ECR_CONNECTION,
    environment=SNOWFLAKE_ENV_VAR,
)
```

I tried running local airflow setup and it worked fine, However MWAA still giving me issues. I have verified permissions for listing and pulling images from ECR, they have been set appropriately.